# Inheritance in annotations

Tags: java, java-annotations

I'm trying to make a method that returns fields that are annotated with a specific annotation.

I have one annotation (`TestAnn`) that I want to be a superclass for the other two (`AutoSave` and `AutoLoad`).

TestAnn:

```
public @interface TestAnn {

    boolean value() default true;

}
```

AutoSave and AutoLoad (their code are the same):

```
@TestAnn
public @interface AutoSave {


    boolean value() default true;

}
```

Method to get fields:

```
private List<Field> getFields(Mode mode){
    Class<? extends TestAnn> an;
    if (mode == Mode.SAVE){
        an = AutoSave.class;
    }
    else if (mode == Mode.LOAD){
        an = AutoLoad.class;
    }
    else{
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    return null;
}
```

So I tried to annotate AutoSave and AutoLoad with `@TestAnn` in hope that it is how inheritance works for annotations. But when I try to assign a specific annotation class to wildcard `<? extends TestAnn>`, the compiler says I can't do that.

So is there some sort of inheritance for annotations? If you provide code for my specific case it would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do in `getFields` exactly?

Comment: @Sweeper Get all the fields with the appropriate (AutoLoad or AutoSave) annotation on them.

Comment: Annotations are not themselves polymorphic.  They cannot extend other annotations, nor any other interface for that matter.  The dupe targets are pretty old, but the situation has not changed.

Comment: @JohnBollinger So how do I get all the class fields with dynamically defined annotation?

Comment: What does that have to do with polymorphic annotations?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Nothing. I'm just trying to solve my problem...

Comment: Though I should clarify: all annotations do extend `java.lang.annotation.Annotation`, so they have (very) limited polymorphism in that sense.  You might find that useful, but I don't see its direct use as *necessary* here.